# Creating Conditional Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, conditional-statements

I am trying to create an Array in Javascript with some key:value pair. My initial array looks likes this:

```
var data = {
isPublic : true,
distance : 500,
noOfPlayer : 10
}
```

Now there is a checkbox, upon which upon checking I need to add more data to array. Say I check a box and need to update the array with its value and make the array look like this:

```
var data = {
isPublic : true,
distance : 500,
noOfPlayer : 10,
typePlay: 'amateur'
}
```

Can this be done, because I tried creating object with Key:value and pushing it to the array, but it gives and output as below:

```
var data = 
[
{
  isPublic : true,
  distance : 500,
  noOfPlayer : 10,
},
{
  typePlay: 'amateur'
}
]
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Ayush

Comment: please add the rest of the code as well - at least the part whre you push somthing.

Comment: The problem is that `data` is an object, not array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `object["property"] = value` or `object.property = value` to add a new property with its value

```js
var data = {
"isPublic" : true,
"distance" : 500,
"noOfPlayer" : 10
};

data["typePlay"] = "amateur";
data.typePlay2 = "amateur";

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Weedoze.. worked like a charm :)